# How to remove duplicate object property in Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of messages between me and different other users, I am trying to filter this array to only contain a single occurrence of a user (e.g In this array there are 10 messages between me and John, where I've been either a sender or a receiver), I'm trying to get a new array containing only a single occurrence of John, the latest message (be it john as a sender or receiver). I also have two messages between me and Jane, (in one I was the sender, the other message I was the receiver), I would like to also have only a single occurrence of messages between me and Jane.

So at the end I'm trying to have an array containing three messages,

-one with Thomas

-one with Jane

-one with John

If anyone has a solution pls share

```
[
{
    "_id": "5f58b7a4075626065aaa752a",
    "message": "Hi",
    "receiver": "5f004feae528a90017327f3b",
    "sender": "5f4ea9d045cc6b736870a076",
    "senderInfo": {
        "_id": "5f58b7a4075626065aaa752b",
        "name": "Thomas",
    },
    "receiverInfo": {
        "_id": "5f58b7a4075626065aaa752c",
        "name": "ME",
    }
},
{
    "_id": "5f57f190075626065aaa600d",
    "message": "When I click on \"go to session\", I just see myself. I doubt the connection was established",
    "receiver": "5f4e646822ab43702ee29ebb",
    "sender": "5f004feae528a90017327f3b",
    "senderInfo": {
        "_id": "5f57f190075626065aaa600e",
        "name": "Me",
    },
    "receiverInfo": {
        "_id": "5f57f190075626065aaa600f",
        "name": "John",
    }
},
{
    "_id": "5f57f08d075626065aaa5eed",
    "message": "I think I lost all the calls. The session takes a while to load",
    "receiver": "5f4e646822ab43702ee29ebb",
    "sender": "5f004feae528a90017327f3b",
    "senderInfo": {
        "_id": "5f57f08d075626065aaa5eee",
        "name": "Me ",
    },
    "receiverInfo": {
        "_id": "5f57f08d075626065aaa5eef",
        "name": "John",

    }
},
{
    "_id": "5f57f068075626065aaa5eae",
    "message": "Kk",
    "receiver": "5f004feae528a90017327f3b",
    "sender": "5f4e646822ab43702ee29ebb",
    "senderInfo": {
        "_id": "5f57f068075626065aaa5eaf",
        "name": "John",
    },
    "receiverInfo": {
        "_id": "5f57f068075626065aaa5eb0",
        "name": "Me",
    },
},
{
    "_id": "5f57efd3075626065aaa5e2d",
    "message": "I'm available now",
    "receiver": "5f4e646822ab43702ee29ebb",
    "sender": "5f004feae528a90017327f3b",
    "senderInfo": {
        "_id": "5f57efd3075626065aaa5e2e",
        "name": "Me"
    },
    "receiverInfo": {
        "_id": "5f57efd3075626065aaa5e2f",
        "name": "John",
    }
},
{
    "_id": "5f57ee75075626065aaa5dcb",
    "message": "Ok",
    "receiver": "5f4e646822ab43702ee29ebb",
    "sender": "5f004feae528a90017327f3b",
    "senderInfo": {
        "_id": "5f57ee75075626065aaa5dcc",
        "name": "Me",
    },
    "receiverInfo": {
        "_id": "5f57ee75075626065aaa5dcd",
        "name": "John",
    }
},
{
    "_id": "5f57ee5f075626065aaa5d99",
    "message": "Mark available let me try ",
    "receiver": "5f004feae528a90017327f3b",
    "sender": "5f4e646822ab43702ee29ebb",
    "attachment": null,
    "type": 1,
    "senderInfo": {
        "_id": "5f57ee5f075626065aaa5d9a",
        "name": "John"
    },
    "receiverInfo": {
        "_id": "5f57ee5f075626065aaa5d9b",
        "name": "Me"
    }
},
{
    "_id": "5f57ee23075626065aaa5d6d",
    "message": "I got the notification but it just didn't connect",
    "receiver": "5f4e646822ab43702ee29ebb",
    "sender": "5f004feae528a90017327f3b",
    "senderInfo": {
        "_id": "5f57ee23075626065aaa5d6e",
        "name": "Me"
    },
    "receiverInfo": {
        "_id": "5f57ee23075626065aaa5d6f",
        "name": "John",
    }
},
{
    "_id": "5f57ede3075626065aaa5d46",
    "message": "Didn't go",
    "receiver": "5f004feae528a90017327f3b",
    "sender": "5f4e646822ab43702ee29ebb",
    "senderInfo": {
        "_id": "5f57ede3075626065aaa5d47",
        "name": "John",
    },
    "receiverInfo": {
        "_id": "5f57ede3075626065aaa5d48",
        "name": "Me",
    }
},
{
    "_id": "5f57edd9075626065aaa5d38",
    "message": "I tried to call",
    "receiver": "5f004feae528a90017327f3b",
    "sender": "5f4e646822ab43702ee29ebb",
    "senderInfo": {
        "_id": "5f57edd9075626065aaa5d39",
        "name": "John",
    },
    "receiverInfo": {
        "_id": "5f57edd9075626065aaa5d3a",
        "name": "Me",
    }
},
{
    "_id": "5f57ed8a075626065aaa5d19",
    "message": "Hi",
    "receiver": "5f4e646822ab43702ee29ebb",
    "sender": "5f004feae528a90017327f3b",
    "senderInfo": {
        "_id": "5f57ed8a075626065aaa5d1a",
        "name": "Me",
    },
    "receiverInfo": {
        "_id": "5f57ed8a075626065aaa5d1b",
        "name": "John",
    },
},

{
    "_id": "5f58b7a4075626065aaa752a",
    "message": "Hi",
    "receiver": "5f004feae528a90017327f3b",
    "sender": "5f4ea9d045cc6b736870a076",
    "senderInfo": {
        "_id": "5f58b7a4075626065aaa752b",
        "name": "Jane",
    },
    "receiverInfo": {
        "_id": "5f58b7a4075626065aaa752c",
        "name": "ME",
    }
},

{
    "_id": "5f58b7a4075626065aaa752a",
    "message": "Hi",
    "receiver": "5f004feae528a90017327f3b",
    "sender": "5f4ea9d045cc6b736870a076",
    "receiverInfo": {
        "_id": "5f58b7a4075626065aaa752b",
        "name": "Jane",
    },
    "senderInfo": {
        "_id": "5f58b7a4075626065aaa752c",
        "name": "ME",
    }
},

]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried array set, I've also tried looping and checking instance of each object

Comment: Post your code, or no one will know what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

There's likely more than one way to do this. Without any more context, it sounds like you are trying to do this in some Javascript application code, and this is how I would do that, assuming that's the right level to solve your problem:

Use [array reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). For every message, check if another message with the user is already present in a message in the result array. If not, add the message to the result array, otherwise return the result array.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is extract a distinct key(Names) that you intend to sort the list
with ...then sort

```js
let dJson ='{JSON}'


// GET ALL SENDER OR RECEIVERS NAME AS KEY

let allNames = [] // all mail names , includes dublicate

const p_me = JSON.parse(dJson);

p_me['lol'].forEach(item => {
  if (item.receiverInfo.name.toLowerCase() !== "me") {
    allNames.push(item.receiverInfo.name.toLowerCase())
  } else {
    allNames.push(item.senderInfo.name.toLowerCase())
  }
})




// REMOVE Dublicates Using Set Object 


let names = [...new Set(allNames)];


// Get The New Filtered List 
let MyList = [] // The required list

for (name of names) {
  for (obj of p_me['lol']) {

    if (obj.receiverInfo.name.toLowerCase() == name || obj.senderInfo.name.toLowerCase() == name) {

      //Get the first match and disregard the rest for the same name
      MyList.push(obj)
      break
    }
  }

}
```

Not the best implementation for a very large json file...due to looping over the array twice